# Popup not load if started from Alert Box

Tags: javascript, popup, alert, box

My popup ad code is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//URL'></script>
```

If I insert the url in `window.open` not load.
I tried also with this but nothing:

```
var importantStuff = window.open('http://example.com/waiting.html', '_blank');
```

if I insert it simply in the page works. Why?

Comment: Remove the `src` part and see if it works.

Comment: I insert it in window.open without src, in this way: window.open('URL'); All other links works, only popup ad code not works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
window.open(
  "http://example.com/waiting.html",
  "Example page",
  "outerWidth=600,width=500,innerWidth=400,resizable,scrollbars,status"
);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/870qnLew/

Comment: The result not change. The link open and I see only text not load. I think the problem is window.open. I see a website use javascript:doClose for close alertbox and open popup and for him works.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Check the example that I have added and let me if it is what you needed.

Comment: I use already window.open. The window popup start but not load. If I use this code <script type='text/javascript' src='//URL'></script> directly in the page the popup load well. But if I use the URL with window.open not load.